# Does it make sense to a put an entire pipeline inside Jenkins shared library function

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

We have a pipeline responsible for implementing some code quality check. The tool used for code quality is `coverity` and this pipeline is used by so many projects that we decided to put the entire pipeline inside a shared library function like so:

```
def call(Map args) {
    def project = args.project
    def buildCommand = args.buildCommand
    def configFile = args.configFile

    pipeline {
        agent {
            label 'some-label'
        }
        stages {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is that all the projects don't have to write their own pipelines, simply supply the `Map` and invoke this pipeline inside shared library script.

When we are writing unit-tests against this using the `JenkinsPipelineUnit` framework we are running into issues such as having to modify this function just to make the unit-test pass. Makes me wonder whether I am trying to do something that shouldn't be done and whether there is a better way of achieving the same goal?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you can, I'd recommend putting shared code into a shared code repository and have your pipeline runner (in this case Jenkins) check it out with some very thin wrapper as a first step

This allows

- everyone relevant to take part in reviewing changes to it (such as offering a version field as an argument)
- much easier rebuilding of the pipeline runner(s) when they inevitably break
- writing the logic in whatever language you like